Magento2 How to get Customizable dropdown Options of a simple product in phtml file
How to get this https://prnt.sc/HE4LFsRji9fs Customizable option data in a phtml file.
I want to  data in like in this format...
<div class="field required">
            <label class="label" for="select_69">
            <span>Options</span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
            <select name="options[69]" id="select_69" class=" required product-custom-option admin__control-select" title="" data-selector="options[69]" aria-required="true"><option value="">-- Please Select --</option><option value="192" price="30">straight charge +£30.00</option></select></div></div>


Here, I am sharing the solution.. How to get Customizable option data in a phtml file.
<?php 
$product = $block->getProduct();
$options = $product->getOptions();
if ($options && !empty($options)) {
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        if ($option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {   
            ?>
            
            <div class="field required ">
                <label class="label" for="select_<?php echo $option->getId(); ?>">
                    <span><h4><?php echo $option->getTitle(); ?></h4></span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <select name="options[<?php echo $option->getId(); ?>]" id="select_<?php echo $option->getId(); ?>"
                            class="required product-custom-option admin__control-select select-option"
                            title="<?php echo $option->getTitle(); ?>"
                            data-selector="options[<?php echo $option->getId(); ?>]" aria-required="true">
                        <option value=""><?php echo __('-- Please Select --'); ?></option>
                        <?php foreach ($option->getValues() as $value) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $value->getId(); ?>" price="<?php echo $value->getPrice(); ?>">
                                <?php echo $value->getTitle(); ?>
                                <?php if ($value->getPrice() != 0) { ?>
                                    <?php echo __('+'); ?><?php echo $value->getPrice(); ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
          }
      }
   }

?>

